# OpenGL ES 2.0 attach texture to stencil buffer

Tags: opengl-es

It is known, that OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, etc ...

Is it possible to use GL_LUMINANCE, GL_ALPHA textures for this purporses?

```
glGenTextures(1, &byteTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, byteTex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_LUMINANCE, width(), height(), 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, byteTex, 0);
```

In other words - is it possible, to have stencil buffer rendered to texture?

P.S. It is possible to "cover" stenciled area with quad, but....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In ES 2.0, you can only use renderbuffers for the stencil attachment.

From section "Framebuffer Attachment Completeness" in the ES 2.0 spec (page 117):

> If attachment is STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, then image must have a stencil renderable internal format.

Table 4.5 on the same page lists `STENCIL_INDEX8` as the only internal format to be stencil-renderable. And on the previous page, it says:

> Formats not listed in table 4.5, including compressed internal formats, are not color-, depth-, or stencil-renderable, no matter which components they contain.

ES 2.0 is a very minimal version of OpenGL. You're clearly exceeding the scope of ES 2.0. ES 3.0 introduces depth/stencil textures, but still does not support sampling the stencil part of those textures. ES 3.1 introduces sampling the stencil part of depth/stencil textures.

There is a [OES_texture_stencil8](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_stencil8.txt) extension defined, but it looks like a mess to me. It says that it is based on ES 3.0, but then partly references the ES 3.1 spec. And it says that it has a dependency on a OES_stencil_texturing extension, which is nowhere to be found on www.khronos.org, or anywhere else in the Google visible part of the internet. But since it's for ES 3.x, it wouldn't help you anyway.